# How to execute block of statements in then and else in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

This is working fine.

`SELECT (CASE WHEN condition then s1 else s2 end) from table.`

but i am looking for a solution to execute multiple statements like

`SELECT (CASE WHEN condition then s1, s2, s3.. else s4, s5,s6 end) from table.`

Is there is any way to execute block of queries in then and else block or any alternative to do the same?

Something like this.

`select (case when (LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE(substr(var, -2), ' +-.0123456789', ' '))) is NULL) 
then  RTRIM(SUBSTR(var, -2)) as A, LTRIM(SUBSTR(var, 1, (LENGTH(var) - 3))) as B else RTRIM(SUBSTR(var, -4)) as A, LTRIM(SUBSTR(var, 1, (LENGTH(var) - 3))) as B  end) 
from trade`

Currently i am getting

Error(s), warning(s):

ORA-00905: missing keyword

Comment: Help us to understand what you're trying to do by posting some sample data and the desired output derived from that sample. Don't expect us to reverse engineer your business logic from some shonky code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do what you want the way you want to.

I would put the condition in a subquery and then use repeated `case` expressions:

```
select (case when is_numeric = 1 
             then rtrim(substr(var, -2))
             else rtrim(substr(var, -4)) as A,
        end) as a,
       (case when is_numeric = 1
             then ltrim(substr(var, 1, length(var) - 3))
             else ltrim(substr(var, 1, length(var) - 3))
        end) as B
from (select t.*,
             (case when LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE(substr(var, -2), ' +-.0123456789', ' '))) is NULL
                   then 1 else 0
              end) as is_numeric
      from trade t
     ) t
```

Unless I'm mistaken, `B` has the same definition regardless, so you can simplify this to:

```
select (case when is_numeric = 1 
             then rtrim(substr(var, -2))
             else rtrim(substr(var, -4)) as A,
        end) as a,
       ltrim(substr(var, 1, length(var) - 3)) as B
from (select t.*,
             (case when LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE(substr(var, -2), ' +-.0123456789', ' '))) is NULL
                   then 1 else 0
              end) as is_numeric
      from trade t
     ) t
```

Answer (score -1):

A single expression cannot produce multiple columns.
Instead, you can use a union of alternatives:

```
with tab as ( 
  select 1 as choice, var, RTRIM(SUBSTR(var, -2)) as A
        , LTRIM(SUBSTR(var, 1, (LENGTH(var) - 3))) as B 
  from table
  union all
  select 2 as choice, var, RTRIM(SUBSTR(var, -4)) as A
        , LTRIM(SUBSTR(var, 1, (LENGTH(var) - 3))) as B 
  from table
)
select tab.A, tab.B 
from tab 
where tab.choice = case when (LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE(substr(tab.var, -2)
                                    , ' +-.0123456789', ' ')))  is NULL) 
                                then 1 
                                else 2 end
-- not tested
;
```